# Unable to delete folders in trash which containing .svn files

Tags: macos, svn, trash

Now I am stuck with strange errors in my MacBook Pro. I am not able to empty folders in trash which contain .svn files. I tried to surf around the net and unfortunately i am still stuck in it. Is there any scripts or apps which can solve this kinda error. Any quick help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright,after spending a few days, i just found the solution myself by installing [trashit](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8214/trash-it!) to force to delete all the folders in trash. Anyway, thanks a lot for your guys efforts. Appreciate it !.

Answer (score 0):

{svn copy ...} does a "light copy", that is, as long as you don't change files, they don't occupy any disk space.

Open "activity Manager and pick the most like App with a handle locking the file from deletion.. like Finder press i {inspect} > press [open files & ports] and look for your file kill the app locking the file so you can delete the trash.

miscellaeous info on SVN

"Branches are handy for developing larger features (especially if you
temporarily break muse and then fix it again). You might want to ask
why you shouldn't simply develop in your local working copy, and then
commit a huge chunk. Well, this has multiple reasons:

- with branches, you'll have a history, because there are many small
  commits. this makes bisecting for finding a bug possible.
- when you develop your feature publicly, others can check out half-done
  versions, and already test the one half. they also could fix bugs.
- another advantage of keeping it public is: others can see whether you
  may exclude some use case and inform you about that in time. otherwise
  you'd spend lots of work in a design which was obsolete from the
  beginning.
- and it shows that there's something going on :)

also, branching makes "feature freezes" easier, for release planning.

General note: ^/trunk means [url of the repo]/trunk. when you're inside
a working copy, svn understands the ^/trunk notation.
i assume you're inside some working copy

whenever merging, make sure you're in the correct directory!

- List item"

Comment: `svn copy` is a server-side command. This sounds more like a working copy (client-side) issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make use of the command 'lsof' (list open files) to take a look what program locks these file.
Of course you have to use the terminal for stuff like this and perhaps an administrator/root account.